# The proof that the subspace $l_{2}^D$ is not closed.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I know how to prove that the following subspace is not complete:

[image]

But does this help in proving that it is not closed? if so how? if not then how can I prove that it is not closed?

Comment: What ls $l_2^D$? The space that you say is complete is not complete and is not closed in $l_2$.

Comment: A complete metric space is necessarily closed, since a convergent sequence is trivially a Cauchy sequence...

Comment: @copper.hat  sorry I corrected my mistakes.

Comment: Any element of $l_2$ whose first element is zero can be approximated arbitrarily closely by a sequence with a finite number of non zero components.

Comment: I know that the definition of completeness is: "Any Cauchy sequence is convergent to an element in my space ". is not this the reverse of what you said ? or I have a mistake? @Math1000

Comment: That is correct. A space is **closed** if any *convergent* sequence in that space has its limit in that space. Any convergent sequence is Cauchy, and so..?

Comment: I got your idea @Math1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the sequence $x=(0,{1 \over 2},...,{1 \over n},... ) \in l_2$.

If $x_n = (0,{1 \over 2},...,{1 \over n},0,0,... )$ then $x_n $ is a member of the subspace in question and $x_n \to x$, but $x$ is not
a member of the subspace.